# How to add service reference in visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf, visual-studio-2017

i am trying to add a service reference in visual studio 2017, when i add this via right click on reference -> add service reference  then it's giving following error [image]

as per "**https://aka.ms/odatavsclientguidance**" site when i go in `Extension and Updates` in `Tools`. i am not finding `OData Connect`
[image]

please help me to add service reference in Visual studio  2017.

Comment: The link you added does not include Visual Studio 2017 as a supported version.

Comment: Yes, But when i add reference in VS 2017, In error detail same link provided...can u please help how can i add service reference ?

Comment: Can you not use VS 2015?

Comment: i just installed VS 2017, clients wants project development in VS 2017...before 2017 i used to use VS 2013

Comment: i downloaded community version, don't know this problem coming only in community version or in ultimate and all also

Comment: Never used the OData Code generator, but can you not create the project in a previous version of VS, generate the relevant code and then open project in VS 2017?

Comment: i tried same...but got conversion error of MVC

Comment: FYI: Same problem in VS 2017 Enterprise as well. Still researching it...

Comment: @RodgerCooley, i am also still searching...currently i am using VS 2015...in this Odata is working fine.

Comment: In your Solution Explorer, right click on References, Add Connected Service then select Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider, you'll get a Wizard-like window to add a Service Reference just like in VS2015. Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2017 15.5 or later, in Solution Explorer,

- Right mouse click the project
- Select Add...
- Select Connected Service
- Select Microsoft WCF Web Services
- Paste in the web service URL

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide